# Flutter: Could not instantiate image codec when calling Image.memory

Tags: image, exception, flutter, dart

I want to create a simple profile picture for my app.
I thought it would work like this, but it throws an exception when calling it and I
can't figure out why.

```
Widget _buildProfilePicture(double size) {
      if (user.profileImage != null) {
        return ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
          child: Image.memory(
            user.profileImage,
            width: size,
            height: size,
          ),
        );
      }
}
```

The attribute `user.profileImage` has the datatype `Uint8List`.

When I call it, it throws this exception:

```
════════ Exception caught by image resource service ════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following _Exception was thrown while resolving an image:
Exception: Could not instantiate image codec.

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      _futurize (dart:ui/painting.dart:4304:5)
#1      instantiateImageCodec (dart:ui/painting.dart:1682:10)
#2      PaintingBinding.instantiateImageCodec (package:flutter/src/painting/binding.dart:88:12)
#3      MemoryImage._loadAsync (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:714:18)
#4      MemoryImage.load (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:706:14)
...
Image provider: MemoryImage(Uint8List#2592a, scale: 1.0)
Image configuration: ImageConfiguration(bundle: PlatformAssetBundle#633d8(), devicePixelRatio: 2.6, locale: en_US, textDirection: TextDirection.ltr, size: Size(50.0, 50.0), platform: android)
Image key: MemoryImage(Uint8List#2592a, scale: 1.0)
```

I think it's caused by `Image.memory`.

Thanks for answers in advance!

Comment: It probably not one of the supported formats, like BMP, PNG or JPEG.

Comment: I retrieve my image from a server and I get `content-type: [image/png]` as the content-type, so it should be a png right?

Comment: what are the first 8 bytes of `user.profileImage`? in hex? is it `89 50 4E 47 0D 0A 1A 0A`? if not, compare them with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures

Comment: If the image is coming from the network, try `Image.network`

Comment: Ok, so I think it may be that the image i get from the server is corrupted, but I'm not quite sure yet.

Comment: By the way, the image was corrupted.

Comment: I have the same problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into the exact same problem. The image was a png file that was properly 'loaded' in the pubspec file. However I got the same error:

```
Exception: Could not instantiate image codec.
```

It turned out the image was corrupted.
Replacing the image solved it for me.

Comment: Yes that was the problem with mine too!

Answer (score 2):

It could be that you have to encode it to an appropriate type with `https://pub.dev/packages/image` like:

```dart
    import 'package:image/image.dart' as imageUtils;

    var encodedImage = Image.memory(
                    imageUtils.encodePng(user.profileImage));
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar exception when trying to load the contacts avatar using [Image.memory](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Image/Image.memory.html). It basically takes in [Uint8List](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-typed_data/Uint8List-class.html) as the input source.

And I found that you receive that exception when the list is empty(length=0). so you can prevent that exception by putting a check something like this

```
Widget myAvatarWidget(){
    final imageBytes = contact.avatar;
    return imageBytes == null || imageBytes.length == 0
           ? showDefaultWidget(path: profileUrl, radius: 30.0)
           : ClipRRect(
               borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
               child: Image.memory(imageBytes)
             );
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was try load and image in base64 type jpg or png with `Image.memory()` but the image was svg, so i just wrote:

```
 String _imageBase64;
 Uint8List bytes;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final size = getMediaSize(context);
    _imageBase64 = widget.reward.img;
    const Base64Codec base64 = Base64Codec();

    bytes = base64.decode(_imageBase64);
    return SvgPicture.memory(
      bytes,
      fit: BoxFit.fill,
      height: size.width * 0.1,
      width: size.width * 0.1,
    );}
```

I hope it helps, happy coding.